# Behave as a PC browser

Tags: browser

I want to watch streams of a [TV channel](http://www.voxnow.de/). That channel also offers an unfree app to do that.

When I visit the site with my tablet I am forced to download the app to use the site. From my PC I can access the site normally.

How can I set my tablet browser to behave as a PC browser?

<sub>I tried the default Android and Chrome browsers.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Android browser (AOSP) and Chrome there is an option called *Request desktop site*. This can be accessed via the options menu for the browser. That would change the browser user-agent to desktop and display the website as displayed on PC.

But this has to be done for each tab I believe, there is no permanent solution.